# Replace links in content with hyperlinks using Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string which contains a user's blog content.  If they include the following:

```
www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
```

in their blog post, I want PHP to replace these occurrences with a real hyperlink, but maintain the original substring (i.e. not change `www.google.com` to `http://www.google.com`).

Does anybody know how I might do this with PHP and regular expressions?  I've tried this:

```
echo preg_replace('/((www|http:\/\/)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

But this only succeeds if you end the link with a space. Fails if you end it with a comma or full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\b(?:(http(s?):\/\/)|(?=www\.))(\S+)/is',
             '<a href="http$2://$3" target="_blank">$1$3</a>',
             $content);
```

Comment: The same scenario I need it in Jquery/Javascript. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/<a (.*?)href=[\"\'](.*?)\/\/(.*?)[\"\'](.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i';
$new_content = preg_replace($pattern, '$5', $content);
```

Comment: The same scenario I need it in Jquery/Javascript. Can anyone help ?